# How do I switch from one activity to another in an onDown() method of myCustomerRecyclerView()?

Tags: android

This is `MyCustomRecyclerView.java`

```
public class MyCustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;

public MyCustomRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);

}

public MyCustomRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);

}

public MyCustomRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, gestureListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);

}

private final GestureDetector.OnGestureListener gestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (getParent() != null)
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onFling: ");
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), " Swipe Down ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent hmmIntent = new Intent(getContext(),HmmActivity);
        startActivity(hmmIntent);
        return super.onDown(e);
    }
};
```

The,
   `Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getContext(),HomeActivity);
   startActivity(homeIntent);'
lines are giving me the error. I have MyRecyclerViewAdapter, MainActivity and HomeActivity classes apart from this one.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Could you please share your error log?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol variable HomeActivity 
error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)

Answer (score 0):

this is a view class, a reusable component, so don't write project specific methods or callbacks in views. Write your recyclerview onClick method in your main activity as below;

put this to your mainActivity onCreate() method:

```
        recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code here
        }
    });
```

Also you should call finish(); after startActivity()

Comment: But, I don't want to switch the activity after a click (onClick), but after a swipe down (onDown).
How do I use onDown in my MainActivity?

Comment: But your intent is in onDown() method :). onDown means click.